# Rails app on Heroku with Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, heroku, session-timeout, puma

We have a Rails app running on a single Heroku instance configured with Puma. We are having performance issues that are causing H14 errors (session timeouts).

We run anywhere from 2-5 Web dynos depending on traffic. We run 3 Worker dynos for our background processes. I have increased our Web dynos from 1x (512mb) to 2x (1gb) and removed our logging service Papertrail, which seemed to be causing memory leaks. This has helped a little bit.

We are receiving anywhere from 30-60 RPMs depending on the time of day.

Here is our Puma config:

```
workers Integer(ENV['PUMA_WORKERS'] || 2)
threads Integer(ENV['MIN_THREADS']  || 8), Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 12)

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # worker specific setup
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
                Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool'] = ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 12
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

We have implemented the Heroku Rack Timeout gem and have used the default timeout setting of 15 seconds, but this has not helped the situation at all. It possibly could have made it worse, so we removed it.

Does anyone know of the optimal configuration for an app like ours with the traffic metrics described above? Any config suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: H14s are for no web dynos running. Are you sure you're not getting R14s?

Comment: Brian, we're having problems with Puma as well, which might be related. Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: Same problem here. The rails app crashes (timeout and over memory consumption). Did you find a working configuration? What version of rails? Of ruby?